# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having this error when trying to mark a checkbox in the listbox

The objective of this method is loading a controller user list.

It selects the users returned with checkbox.

***Error line: var users = $.parseJSON(loadAction);***

**First Function**

```
function loadAction() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("LoadUsersCheckBox", "User")",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                idUser: idUser
            }
        });
    };

function loadUsers() {
    loadAction();

    var users = $.parseJSON(loadAction);

    $("#UsuariosInformados option").each(function() {
        var opt = $(this),
            value = opt.attr("value");

        opt.removeAttr("selected");

        if (users.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            opt.attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller LoadUsersCheckBox**

```
public JsonResult LoadUsersCheckBox(int? idUser)
{
    var users =  Service.GetSystemUsers(idUser);
    var model = users.Select(x => new
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Description = x
                });

    return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Whats my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var users = $.parseJSON(loadAction);
```

`loadAction` is a function. You can't parse it as json. Any json parsing should probably be in the `success` callback of `$.ajax`. At the moment you are doing a HTTP GET request, discarding the result, and parsing the javascript function object (although not in that order).

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Gravel mentioned in his answer, you should not be passing the function to the parseJSON method. parseJSON method accepts a json string and convert that to corresponding js object so that you will have the dictionary like syntax to access properties of the resulting js object.( *ex :someObj.SomeProperty* )

What you should be doing is, using the array you receive from your server inside the success event of your ajax call.

```
function loadUsers() {
    var idUser = 5; // hard coded for demo . Use a real value
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ReportScore", "Home")",
        type: "GET",
        data: { idUser: idUser },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#UsuariosInformados option").each(function () {
                var opt = $(this);
                value = opt.attr("value");

                opt.removeAttr("selected");
                 // Read further about this if condition check .....
                if (data.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                    opt.attr("selected", "selected");
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

I really don't understand what you are trying to do with the result array received. It looks like you are trying to set one option in the select element as the selected item. Usually, you can use the `val()` method to do that.

```
$("#UsuariosInformados").val(25);
```

Assuming `25` is the value of one of the options(*which you want to be selected*) available in the select element.

Also, From your action method, you are returning an array of items and each item has a `Value` and `Description` property(both having the same value) and you are comparing(*indexOf call*) it against the single string value ( value of each option item in the loop). You will never get  a true result for your comparison. You probably should fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error and found out to be a little more tricky to overcome than a string issue!

Here is a short explanation for others in the same case.

The error came up while instantiating an object, **using the *new* keyword**, into the JSON string.

Example code that triggers this particular error:

```
var nobj = function(){this.status='ok'};
var strjson2 = '{"display": "case 4","status":new nobj()}';
var obj2 = JSON.parse(strjson2);
```

Here is the JSfiddle that demonstrates different case scenarios to get to this error: https://jsfiddle.net/dv59b1no/1/

There might be a way to fix this particular error, but I am not aware of it.  If you replace the object creation, the JSON.parse will work fine.

I hope this will be useful to someone!